# URL to JQuery / JQuery UI in Zend Framework Application.ini

Tags: zend-framework

does i realy have to define full url in my application.ini if i want to use jquery local?

```
resources.jquery.localpath    = "/websitex/public/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"
resources.jquery.ui_localpath = "/websitex/public/js/library/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.js"
resources.jquery.stylesheet   = "/websitex/public/css/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"
```

Or is there something like "APPLICATION_PATH" for the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use APPLICATION_PATH in ini files. Contants are translated to their respective values. But you might need the actual URI address, not the server absolute address. From what I see, the code should be like:

```
resources.jquery.localpath    = "/js/library/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"
resources.jquery.ui_localpath = "/js/library/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.js"
resources.jquery.stylesheet   = "/css/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"
```

Assuming /websitex/public/ is you server's document root.

Comment: then your option is to preppend $this->view->baseUrl() to that, problem is that it can't be done using the ini file...